# Comparing one implementation with two methods having O(1), O(n) complexity with another having O(log n) for both of them, which is better?

Tags: time-complexity

Let's assume implementation A and B provides the same two methods f and g with similar space complexity. The usage frequency of these two methods is roughly the same. However, the complexity of f and g method provided by A is O(1) and O(n), while the complexity of both methods provided by B is O(logn). Can we say B is more efficient than A? If so what is the formal reason for such analysis?

Comment: It's sketchy even to say that a single O(1) algorithm is always more efficient than an O(n) algorithm, in the normal / most useful sense of "more efficient".

Comment: Note that `0.5 O(1) + 0.5 O(n) = O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, I think they are not really comparable (just think about data structure choice without any operation load info: often comes down to personal choices).

Personally, I would say that B is going to be considered more efficent because of the following:

Given that the frequency will be roughly the same, consider a run of both f and g:

For A: `O(1) + O(n) -> O(n)`

For B: `O(log n) + O(log n) -> O(log n)`